# fopen data put into database

Tags: php, mysql, fopen, fgets

i read a data from another webserver with **fopen** .. so if i put the link in webbrowser it shows me on screen some data like:

> **|values|value|value|value|value|value|**

every value can be 2 or more letters and every datastring is 6 values long. more datastrings will follow directly after this

so in php to show the data is..

```
$fb=@fopen("http://www.someurl.de/somefolder/?typ=typ...","r");
```

this is no problem

Now how do I get this data from the screen / script in my database

i think i can catch the values with **fget** but i dont know how to separate every value to put it in single database columns (to put 6 entrys and repeat from beginning from next datastring to put in 6 entrys and so on)

any Ideas ?

Comment: `$values = exlpode('|', $fb)` and then you can `foreach` over the values and build an insert string.

Comment: There is always a | as separator?

Comment: It begins with no separator and ends with a separator

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$values = explode('|', trim($values,'|'));
```